# Run Python function from within CherryPy webpage with django

Tags: python, django, cherrypy

My project is a client/server model project with Python, CherryPy and Django.

The Python program has various server like functions (adding/removing/editing stuff from/to the database, running commands, etc).

It's a SQLite database so I would want the server to be the one solely charge of writing to the database and the client WebApp is just a portal into what the database has as far as values and telling the server what to do.

When the python program starts one of its tasks is to initializes a CherryPy server that hosts a Django website as sort of a GUI to the server app.

I use the following thread to start the CherryPy Web server:

```
class ClientThread(object):
  HOST = get_setting_val('BindIP') # Function to read "BindIP" from an ini file.
  PORT = int(get_setting_val('Port')) # Function to read setting from ini file
  DIR = get_setting_val('InstallDir') # function to read setting from ini file.
  STATIC_ROOT = DIR + '/static/'

  def mount_static(self, url, root):
    """
    :param url: Relative url
    :param root: Path to static files root
    """
    config = {
        'tools.staticdir.on': True,
        'tools.staticdir.dir': root,
        'tools.expires.on': True,
        'tools.expires.secs': 86400
    }
    cherrypy.tree.mount(None, url, {'/': config})

  def run(self):
    cherrypy.config.update({
        'server.socket_host': self.HOST,
        'server.socket_port': self.PORT,
        'engine.autoreload_on': False,
        'log.screen': True,
    })
    self.mount_static(settings.STATIC_URL, self.STATIC_ROOT)

    cherrypy.tree.graft(WSGIHandler())
    cherrypy.engine.start()
    print("[Info]: Client started. Use http://{0}:{1} to access the WebApp.".format(self.HOST,self.PORT))
    cherrypy.engine.block()

  def init(self):
    print("[Info]: Starting Client WebApp...")
    cThread = Thread(target=self.run)
    cThread.start()

  def stop(self):
    pass # Pass for now, shutdown server later
```

I need to have a way that if a user, for example, clicks a button on a Django webpage hosted by the CherryPy webserver, it maps back to a function of the main python app.

So for example, my django app has a template which includes a button to "doSomething" with the specific ID in the database (change a value, for example):

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ id }}/doSomething">doSomething</a>
</div>
```

That template leads back to a view:

```
def doSomething(request, id):
  # Run the function "doSomething" passing value 'id' to the function in main.py
```

It would then map back to a function or even potentially a class method in the main python app:

```
def doSomething(id):
  cur=sqlConn.cursor()
  q = "INSERT INTO table(foo) VALUES(?)"
  try:
    cur.execute(q, id)
    sqlConn.commit()
  except Exception as err:
    print('[Error] Query doSomething Failed: %s\nError: %s' % (q, str(err)))
```

Is what I'm going after even possible in the setup I've chosen?

Edit:
The only requirement is that the GUI is accessible via Web Browser and use of python as the language is preferred.

Thanks for your insight.

Comment: You could  do something like that if you used cherrypy as a framework not just the webserver (cheroot). Is the use of django mandatory?

Comment: @cyraxjoe Not exactly. Django is what I know so it's what I started with. I'm no where near being complete on this project so I'm flexible. The only requirement is that the GUI has to be accessible via web browser. Edited my answer to include that information.